# Rotate back from the questions list opens post body instead of questions list again

Tags: bug, ios-app

Being on the questions list in portrait mode and rotating the device two times (to landscape mode and again to portrait) opens the post page instead of the questions list.

1. > [image: Questions portrait]
2. > [image: Landscape]
3. > [image: Post]

I think rotating back should return to the same state from which I began.

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad 7,3)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)